# Problems with creating custom action in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, custom-action

I'm trying to create a really simple custom action for a simple TEST, but when I run the Setup project it isn't working.
Here is the code from the installer class. For now I just want to show a simple console message, to comprove that the code is executing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;


namespace InstallerRemoveCM
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class InstallerRemoveCM : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public InstallerRemoveCM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);

        Console.Write("aasdasdasda1");
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);

        Console.Write("aasdasdasda2");

    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Rollback(savedState);
        Console.Write("aasdasdasda3");
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
        Console.Write("aasdasdasda4");
    }
}
```

}

I tried everything in the CustomActionData:

/target =  [TARGETDIR]

/target = "[TARGETDIR]"

/target = "[TARGETDIR]\"

when the CustomActionData is empty, the installation runs till the end, but no console message is shown. Otherwise, if the CustomActionData has some of the parameters mentioned before, the install throw this message:

error 1001 exception occurred while initializing the installation

Well people, any help will be wellcome
Thanks.

Comment: You can't use console.write out of a VS 2010 custom action because those custom actions are not running in the interactive user's context. If it's an Everyone install that code runs with the system account and the system account cannot interact with the desktop and probably doesn't even have a console you can write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I change the code, with te objective of delete a directory ("C:\Program Files(x86)\ .... \cm") after the installation process. And now the commit part looks like this:

....

```
   [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);
        var DirectorioInstalacao = Path.GetFullPath(Context.Parameters["targetdir"] + "/cm");
        File.Delete(DirectorioInstalacao.ToString());            
    }
```

...
The CustomActionData has this: /targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"

So now the instructions contained on the "Installer Class" are executed by the setup project, but an other error is showing up:

"Error 1001. An exception occurred during the installation configuration phase. This exception will be ignored and installation will continue. But the application might not work properly after the completion of installation. Access to the path "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ .... \ cm" was denied"

Or something like that, cos my OS is in Portuguese.

Please, Someone knows how to solve that problem?

Comment: You should not do a + to build a path. It's a bad practice that in this case may be causing the problem. You should do a Path.Combine. So it might be a security issue but first use Path.Combine because 1) Targetdir already ends with a backslash and 2) You are using a forward slash which even in Portuguese is probably incorrect.